# How to generate form and redirect Submit button to a new page?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new with Symfony2. I have page `rapport` and `rapport/addnew` and I am using the same form for both. What I need to do is to redirect to `addnew` when the user fill the form in `rapport` and click submit button.

Here is the function I am using in my `DefaultController`:

```
public function showListAction (Request $request)
{   
    $mission = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('LRC203Bundle:Mission')
                    ->findAll();
    $form = $this->createForm(new RapportType(), $mission);
    return $this->render('LRC203Bundle:Default:rapport.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'mission' => $mission ));
}
```

and this is my html.twig:

```
{% block body %}
    {% block missionsList %}
        <ul>
            {% for m in mission %}
                <li>    {{m.car}}   </li>
                <li>    {{m.name}}  </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block newMission %}
        {{ form(form) }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Controller action**

```
public function rapportAction(Request $request) { 
    $mission = new Mission(); 
    $form = $this->createForm(new RapportType(), $mission); 
    $form->handleRequest($request); 

    if($form->isValid()) { 
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
        $em->persist($mission); $em->flush(); 
    } 

    return $this->render('LRC203Bundle:Default:rapport.html.twig', 
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView() 
        )
    ); 
}
```

**RapportType**

```
class RapportType extends AbstractType 
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) { 
$builder     
                ->add('car','text') 
                ->add('name','text')
                ->add('save', 'submit'); 
}


public function getName() { 
    return 'rapport'; 
}
```

}
So all I need is to link the Submit button to addnew page.

Comment: You first would need to show your submitAction where we can see what you actually do after you submit the form.

Comment: This is the rapportAction I am using:

    public function rapportAction(Request $request)
 {
  $mission = new Mission();
  
  $form = $this->createForm(new RapportType(), $mission);
  $form->handleRequest($request);
  if($form->isValid())
  {
   $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $em->persist($mission);
   $em->flush();
  }
  return $this->render('LRC203Bundle:Default:rapport.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ));
 }

Comment: please edit your question, this is barely readable :)

Comment: I have a form with a Submit button, once Submit is clicked form information should be saved in the database and it will redirect to another page. 

In my case nothing is happening when I click Submit.

Comment: please also add the RapportType

Comment: I just edited my post

Answer (score 0):

So actually you are on the right track, you just need to add:

```
if($form->isValid()) { 
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
    $em->persist($mission); $em->flush(); 

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_path'));
}
```

And this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect by controller try this

[symfony adwise](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html)

you can try to how figure it out by "action" element of the form, like:

```
<form action="{{ path('task_new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

or by this way

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
->setAction($this->generateUrl('target_route'))
->setMethod('GET')
->add('task', 'text')
->add('dueDate', 'date')
->add('save', 'submit')
->getForm();
```

or

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $obj, array( 'action' => 'whatever you need'));
```

and catch the response